# Is it possible to include a Simulink Coder executable into a feedback loop outside of Matlab?

Tags: simulink

I'm using Simulink to build a subsystem, which will then be built up using Simulink Coder to get an executable. I want to include this executable into my main function that is not necessarily written using Matlab. The main function is to implement a non-real time, desktop deployed feedback loop, i.e., (1) read out the output of the subsystem, (2) calculate a new input based on the reading, (3) send the new input to the subsystem.

I've managed to build-up a desktop deployed executable of the subsystem using RSim target. But in the main function (for test purpose, I am using Matlab to write the main function), the executable is one-off executed, where I can't read its output or assign new input during its running.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**
If you want to do a closed loop simulation, you most certainly need access to the simulink solver internal step() function. This can be achieved when you build a dll file and then include it via the header files etc. in your other simulation engine. But to be able to do this you need an embedded coder license. use the ert_shrlib.tlc target.